# Why do I not receive reputation for answering question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, up-votes, community-user

I check Stack Overflow every day and one thing that surprised me is that the users do not upvote my answers or select my answer as The Answer when my answer is the solution.

Am I missing something here? Because this really bothers me, that I can't collect reputation and this kind of things disappoint me on continuing to contribute to this community.

Comment: 1st of all rather ask that at Meta Stack Overflow than here. 2nd: Just attend to their help center and read about how to write good answers. Beyond that, we can't give you more advice here.

Comment: Yes, we can (see below).

Comment: Also, your question demonstrates that you could improve on your english. Try with writing shorter sentences, that helps a lot.

Comment: People have complained that their [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9508/282094) and [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74271/282094) have not received enough votes for over a decade. It can be discouraging but usually really good posts earn more, sometimes people vote for other reasons. It's always harder when you are starting, and hoping to get the ability to do more. See related posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/how-can-i-get-answers-fast https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202652/282094

Answer (score 14):

It is impossible to know for sure, but I've briefly reviewed the answers that you've given, and I think that I can see a pettern.

First, take a look at the questions that you are choosing to answer.

Several of them show very little effort from the questioner. One, for example, is about how to apply css to just one element on a page. That's the second thing covered by most css tutorials, and *very* easy to find on the web! Based on this lack of effort, I suspect that the questioner simply can't be bothered to upvote or accept your perfectly good answers.

Related to this, I suspect that the questions you've chosen don't attract much interest from other users. They're very much about the specific problem faced by a single user. If people aren't interested in the question, they probably aren't interested in the answers (yours or anyone else's) and so they don't upvote them. My evidence for this is that the questions themselves attract very few votes, and none of the other answers get many votes, either.

Second, look at your answers. They're fine, but not *exceptional*. Even a bad question can be rescued by a superb answer. And while there is nothing wrong with your answers (they're good, actually) they aren't going to make a name for you, either. For example, there was one about using css to make a particular shape of box. Your answer looks perfectly OK (I didn't test it). However, if you had included a couple of images, and a detailed explanation of your technique, some variations, and some ideas of other ways it could be used, then you *might* attract more up-votes (although, given the niche interest in this area, there are no guarantees).

One final observation: its nice to get recognition for your contributions, but if you're here primarily for the rep, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. For example, I don't expect to get much recognition for this answer, but I hope it will help *you*, and that makes it worthwhile for me. Moreover, answering this question has made me think, and that's good for *me*. Even if you don't like what I've said, and nobody else upvotes what I've written, then I still think it has been worthwhile answering.